# Attempting to remove repeated words in a list python

Tags: python, list, words

I'm trying to remove repeated words in a list where it saves the location and word in a file but it doesn't save the word which occurs after the repeated word. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
sen = input("Input a sentence")
sen1 = sen.lower()
sen2 = sen1.split()
sen4 = sen2
f = open("newfile.txt", "w+")
for words in sen2:
    print(words)
    ok = sen1.count(words)
    print(ok)
    sent = sen4.index(words)
    print(sent)
    f.write(str(sent))
    f.write(str(words))
    if ok > 1 :
        while ok > 0:
            sen2.remove(words)
            ok = ok-1
            if ok == 0:
                break
f.close()
```

Comment: Use a `set`; check if the word is `in` it already; if not, save it, along with the position, else do nothing. Also, not altering your inputs is usually a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a common mistake, modifying a list while you are looping over its items.

Inside the loop `for words in sen2:` do sometimes execute `sen2.remove(words)`, which modifies the list `sen2`. Strange things happened when you do this.

To avoid this, make a deep copy of the list `sen2` with `sen2copy = sen2[:]`, and loop over one of them and modify the other one. You could do this with

```
sen2copy = sen2[:]
for words in sen2copy:
```

or, if you want to be brief,

```
for words in sen2[:]:
```

If you don't understand the notation, `sen2[:]` is a slice of `sen2` from the beginning to the end. In other words, it copies each item in `sen2` to the new list. If you leave out the brackets and colon you just copy a reference to the entire list, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Martinio: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Not sure whats wrong now
    Input a sentence hello Hello what is this
    hello
    2
    0
    hello
    2
    0
    what
    1
    0
    is
    2
    1
    this
    1
    1 
    ['what', 'this']